Can I interpret the size of my regression coefficient when I only control for confounders and not non-confounding covariates?
I am very confused at the moment, for my bachelor's thesis I am performing a Panel Individual Fixed Effects analysis and have only controlled for confounders.
I was under the assumption that when I control for confounders only, I can interpret the direction of the causal effect of the IV on the DV and not the size of the effect. Is this true?
I thought that controlling for confounders meant you can interpret the sign of the regression estimator and only when you control for al covariates, so also non-confounding predictors, that you can confidently interpret both the direction and magnitude of the effect.
However, I have now had a discussion with someone who said I can and should interpret both the sign and size of my Independent variable of interest.
So my question is, can you interpret both the sign AND size of the independent variable of interest if I have only controlled for confounders and not non-counfounding covariates?

Of interest:  https://web.stanford.edu/~knutson/nfc/dawes79.pdf though it probably doesn't answer your question directly.
